# spliting a data frame and then saving them into two separate dfs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns as `id,program,name,add`
Some of the records don't have any values for the `name` and `add` columns (i.e. contains *NaN* values).
I want to split this dataframe into two in such a way that the first df1 contains all the values under `id,program,name,add` i.e. no null values (only those records that contain values under each column); and the second df2 contains only those records wherein there's no value under both the `name` and `add` column. If either of `name` and `add` has any value then it should go into df1, df2 should contain only those records wherein both the columns have NaN values.

The question may seem stupid to some, but I've just started using python, so still a newbie.

the sample data looks like this:

```
id, program,name,add
142, FOO, Sherlock, Baker street
934, FOOFOO, Harry, Hogwards
229, ABC,NaN,NaN
420, XYZ,NaN,USA
619, DEF,NaN,NaN
```

desired output should be something like this:

df1:

```
id,program,name,add
142, FOO, Sherlock, Baker street
934, FOOFOO, Harry, Hogwards
420, XYZ,NaN,USA
```

df2:

```
id,program,name,add
229, ABC,NaN,NaN
619, DEF,NaN,NaN
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` created by `isnull` ([`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)) and then check all `True`s per row by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
mask = df[['name','add']].isnull().all(axis=1)
#pandas 0.21.0+
#mask = df[['name','add']].isna().all(axis=1)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]

print (df1)
    id program      name           add
0  142     FOO  Sherlock  Baker street
1  934  FOOFOO     Harry      Hogwards
3  420     XYZ       NaN           USA

print (df2)
    id program name  add
2  229     ABC  NaN  NaN
4  619     DEF  NaN  NaN
```

Detail:

```
print (df[['name','add']].isnull())
    name    add
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
3   True  False
4   True   True
```